# XPages: viewPanel and Filtered results with Sortable Columns

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I am loosing hair over this: I am writing a small XPage application on Lotus Domino 8.5.3. I want to use data from a view which I can filter by a key (see this.keys below) while having sortable column headers. To do this I am using a viewPanel and it works as expected until I try to sort a column, and then all results disappear (the table is empty).

If I remove the "this.keys" block, then the column sorting works. If I add it back, the data is initially filtered as expected, but as soon as I try to filter a column, the page refreshes and all records are gone (the table is now empty).

I've spent several hours trying work arounds but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Alex

The XPage code in it's entirety looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    pageTitle="Completed Status">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:headTag tagName="link">
            <xp:this.attributes>
                <xp:parameter name="rel" value="stylesheet"></xp:parameter>
                <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/css"></xp:parameter>
                <xp:parameter name="href"
                    value="/interface/css/xpage.css">
                </xp:parameter>
                <xp:parameter name="media" value="screen"></xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <h1>Completed Status</h1>
    <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:text escape="false" id="title"
                    style="font-weight:bold">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        var instanceId = context.getUrlParameter("InstanceID");
                        var title = 'All Recipients';
                        if(instanceId!=null) {
                            var view = session.getCurrentDatabase().getView("(InstancesByInstanceID)");
                            var instance = view.getDocumentByKey(instanceId,true);
                            if(instance!=null) title = 'Recipients for ' + instance.getItemValueString('Title');
                        }
                        title;
                    }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td align="right"></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td colspan="2">
                <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1"
                    var="recipient">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                            layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="recipients"
                            viewName="CompleteStatus">
                            <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                var instanceId = context.getUrlParameter("InstanceID");
                                if(instanceId!=null) return instanceId;
                            }]]></xp:this.keys>
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn1" contentType="HTML"
                        columnName="$16">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader1"
                            value="Category" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Name" id="viewColumn2">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader2"
                            value="Recipient" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="IsCompleted"
                        id="viewColumn3">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Completed"
                            id="viewColumnHeader3" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$13" id="viewColumn4">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Date Last Modified"
                            id="viewColumnHeader4" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$6" contentType="HTML">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader5">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$14"
                        contentType="HTML">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader6">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                </xp:viewPanel>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made the view columns themselves sortable right?  Both directions?  I believe that's key.

Comment: That's the ticket. [Brad blogged about this a while back](Filter by column value); excerpt: "You can enter or compute a value here that will set the ‘keys’ property and filter out the data based on the sorted column in the view, _which is the default sorted column or the column defined in the **Sort column** property_."

Comment: Thanks David, but yes - the columns are sortable in both directions.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The description of the way the "keys" property works does suggest that filtering only works with the default sorted column.  Would you have a link to this blog post by chance?

Answer (score 0):

This just in:  It appears that this is a known problem in Lotus Domino 8.5.3:

Title: LO79744: XPAGES: SORT ANOTHER COLUMN NOT WORK ON "FILTER BY COLUMN VALUE"
URL: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1LO79744